# Can I use communities in a sandbox with out communities on my production org?

Tags: sandbox, customer-community

We don't have communities in our org, and as part of a project I need to show management, an ecommerce/portal solution.

I want to have a communities as one of the candidates, but I don't have it in my sandbox (nor in a dev org)

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can create community in sandbox. We always create community  first in sandbox. First implement everything in sandbox. once completed everything after that we create community  in production and deploy all the related artifacts etc...

Comment: I cant add a contact. No manage external button

Comment: check this out https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000213565&language=en_US

Comment: @Ratan Don't you need to have a community in your production org to have one available in your sandbox?

Comment: @JesseMilburn As per my experience. If production org don't have any community. Still we can create community in sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

@Sarriko If community is not in the production then its not available in your org.

you need to purchase them to work on them . You can't directly create them in SB.

You can create a free developer account in which you will get free community. then you can give demo to your client from this org and if your client like then you can purchase it from production.